# How to update the value of a variable on window resize via jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, resize

I am trying to build a function that triggers when the page is resized and updates the value of a variable if it passes a condition, but I'm unable to update the variable in any capacity. I guess I don't know where I should declare the variable properly or where to update it.

```
var $padding;

    function checkWidth(){
        if (($(window).width) > 750) {
            $padding = 54;
        }
        else if (($(window).width) < 751) {
            $padding = 100;
        }
        $("main").css("padding", $padding + "px 0 0 0");
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        checkWidth();
        console.log($(window).width());
        console.log($padding);
    });
```

In this case, the value of $padding is always undefined.

Placing the $padding variable on top of the checkWidth or resize functions triggers a "$padding is not defined" so I don't know where else it could go. How do I get the value to update?

Comment: You should write padding, not $padding. Remove the $. Initialize padding = 0 because it's always a number and you don't have undefined with this.

Comment: FWIW this is easily done with media queries and CSS.

Comment: imvain2 I need to use jquery because part of the function is triggered under other circumstances that can't be detected with css.

Comment: `width` is a jQuery function, so you'll need to *call* it -- `$(window).width() > 750`, etc.

Comment: are you putting everything inside document ready function?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Remove $ of $padding.

2 - Initialize `var padding = 0;` is better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem is basically the same, now the variable won't update from 0.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work. For me the problem was your IF statement. You were wrapping the width in () forcing it to return true/false and not the numerical value of width. Since you had if and else if with the same problem, your $padding was never being set.

```js
var $padding;

    function checkWidth(){
        if ($(window).width() > 750) {
            $padding = 54;
        }
        else if ($(window).width() < 751) {
            $padding = 100;
        }
        $("main").css("padding", $padding + "px 0 0 0");
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        checkWidth();
        console.log($(window).width());
        console.log($padding);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```